# IBM WebSphere CPU Reduction causing Performance Issues - Application & OS Crash

Tags: java, crash, cpu-usage, websphere-portal

I am assisting a development team on an issue.

- There is a web application hosted on IBM WebSphere.
- For the purpose of cost reduction due to business reasons, there was a decision made to cut the application server processors usage count from 2 to 1.
- Without any change in the number of users accessing the portal, the CPU spike incidents increased from about 6 per year to at least 1 per week.
- An investigation confirmed that the reason for the CPU spikes and application and/or OS crash is because of the increase in the number of users accessing it at the point of the spike.

Which apparently is because of lack of CPU resources.

We need to fix this with a practical solution. Requests to increase the CPUs back to 2 have been rejected and instead been asked to provide a technical fix.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Additional RAM added
2. Heap Memory increased
3. Changed JVM Settings as per PMR recommendation
4. Garbage Collection Frequency reduced
5. Performance Fine Tuning is done
6. Optimized source code

Even after above steps, when the number of users increases above a certain threshold, CPU still spikes and the application server / OS crashes.

Tested briefly by temporarily increasing to 2 CPUs and immediately the CPU spikes and application crashes reduced drastically to agreed acceptable levels.

How to go about this issue?

Can anything technical be done to resolve it, such that CPU usage count is reduced from 2 to 1 but still application runs without spikes or crashes?

I know this question is very subjective and needs to look into the application source code logic. Assuming the code is already fine-tuned to the extent possible, need your advice/recommendation on how to go about it.

I will try to provide as much additional information requested as I can.

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: First you need to find what component within the application is causing the spikes in the CPU, and once you find it then you will have to analyze the code as you mentioned to see if it can be optimized further to help prevent the CPU spikes.  You should start by using the WAS Performance Viewer to help locate the component causing the spikes.

Comment: @Carlos: Thanks for your suggestion. We have already used Tivoli Performance Viewer. Will have a re-look into it.

Answer (score 1):

also you can follow the high cpu mustgather to take some javacores during the high cpu and do a comparative analysis to see what threads are blocking and chewing up the resources